# Hibernate like criteria for more than one rows

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hi i'm using Hibernate criteria for fetching data from database.The code is given below.I want to search a string with two columns. The below code is only checking on one column , How do criteria like with two columns.

```
    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(ActivatedUser.class);
                    c.createAlias("key", "key");
c.createAlias("installedUser", "installedUser");
                        if (searchTerm != null && !searchTerm.isEmpty()) {
    //here i want to check 2 columns for a match
                        c.add(Restrictions.like("key.keyCode", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%"));
                        c.add(Restrictions.like("installedUser.email", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%"));
                    }
```

Comment: two rows or two column?

Comment: if both search is true then only you need to get the data rigt?

Comment: yeah exactly what i want.is it possible do with logical operator??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical AND operator like

```
c.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.like("key.keyCode", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%"), Restrictions.like("installedUser.email", searchTerm.toUpperCase() + "%")));
```

Comment: sorry the code is working. it does not fetch when email and key code typed correctly

Comment: the code worked when i changed the AND to OR, anyway thanks